# How can I identify why my replica's are not starting in the swarm?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm

I have used the following docker swarm command within my manager node to deploy my application.

$ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-stack.yml sb

Here is the docker-stack.yml file.

```
version: "3"
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

  sample_blog:
    image: quay.io/repository/copley/sample_blog
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    networks:
      - frontend
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

This is the output when I run the command:

$ docker service ls

```
ID            NAME             MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
dingz17v0qor  sb_db            replicated  0/1       postgres:9.4
tq3lgqvwx627  sb_sample_blog   replicated  0/2       quay.io/repository/copley/sample_blog
```

Why are my replica's not starting? I have waited over 20minutes.

Comment: Wait longer, can take a really long time to pull stuff. Also run `docker service ps sb_sample_blog` to get the current state of the individual tasks in the service.

Comment: Thanks johnharris85 You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it can simply be a problem due to the `constraints` part of your compose file. Have you checked your Swarm is well configured and that there is a node that matches your constraints? I run into this problem recently.